# Snort / Suricata rules from HOME_NET with rule option flow:to_client

Tags: ids, snort, suricata

Reading through Suricata/Snort IDS rules, I can see examples such as below, and scratching my head to understand how is it feasible that a connection from home_network to external_network can have a flow direction `to_client`? I thought:

1. home_network to external_network always have `(flow:to_server)`: e.g. my browser sends traffic to "google.com"
2. external_network to home_network always have `(flow:to_client)`: e.g. the Google server responds to my browser

`alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"MALWARE-BACKDOOR ghost 2.3 runtime detection";
flow:to_client,established;
content:"ver|3A|Ghost version ";
depth:18; nocase;
content:"server";
distance:0; nocase; pcre:"/^ver\x3aGhost\s+version\s+\d+\x2E\d+\s+server/smi";
metadata:policy balanced-ips drop, policy connectivity-ips drop, policy security-ips drop;
reference:url,www.megasecurity.org/trojans/g/ghost/Ghost2.3.html;
reference:url,www3.ca.com/securityadvisor/pest/pest.aspx?id=42053;
classtype:trojan-activity;
sid:7115;
rev:6;)`

Comment: https://blog.snort.org/2011/09/flow-matters.html

Comment: You are assuming that the rule is for normal and valid flows. But this rule is for malicious traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your thoughts about flow, but in this case, your host is the "Google server" from #2.  The reason it's `flow:to_client` is because, for this alert, the host that captured this log is acting as the server connecting back to the malware client using Ghost as a backdoor.
The `pcre` is matching on a string in packet data called `Ghost version * server/smi`

**References**

[Snort MALWARE-BACKDOOR](https://www.snort.org/rule_docs/1-7115)
[Snort Flow](https://docs.snort.org/rules/options/non_payload/flow)
[Snort pcre](https://docs.snort.org/rules/options/payload/pcre)
[Snort Blog - Flow Matters](https://blog.snort.org/2011/09/flow-matters.html)